# How to determine if "html" or "body" scrolls the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, scroll

The code below is used to find the element that can be scrolled (body or html) via javascript.

```
    var scrollElement = (function (tags) {
        var el, $el, init;
        // iterate through the tags...
        while (el = tags.pop()) {
            $el = $(el);
            // if the scrollTop value is already > 0 then this element will work
            if ( $el.scrollTop() > 0){
                return $el;
            }
            // if scrollTop is 0 try to scroll.
            else if($el.scrollTop( 1 ).scrollTop() > 0) {
                // if that worked reset the scroll top and return the element
                return $el.scrollTop(0);
            }
        }
        return $();
    } (["html", "body"]));

    // do stuff with scrollElement...like:
    // scrollElement.animate({"scrollTop":target.offset().top},1000);
```

This code works perfectly when the height of the `document` is greater than the height of the `window`. However, when the height of the `document` is the same or less than the `window` the method above will *not* work because `scrollTop()` will always be equal to 0. This becomes a problem if the DOM is updated and the height of the `document` grows beyond the height of the `window` after the code runs.

Also, I generally don't wait until document.ready to set up my javascript handlers (this generally works). I *could* append a tall div to the `body` temporarily to force the method above to work BUT that would require the document to be ready in IE (you can't add a node to the body element before the tag is closed). For more on the `document.ready` "anti-pattern" topic [read this](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41/1f5f44b00d5649b5).

**So, I'd love to find a solution that finds the scrollable element even when the `document` is short. Any ideas?**

Comment: why not use if ($el.scrollTop() >= 0) ? EDIT: wow just realized this question is super old

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its been about 5 years since I asked this....but better late than never!

`document.scrollingElement` is now part of the CSSOM spec, but has little to no real-world browser implementation at this point (April 2015). However, you can still find the element...

By using [this polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/document.scrollingElement) by [Mathias Bynens](https://twitter.com/mathias) and [Diego Perini](https://twitter.com/diegoperini).

Which implements this basic solution by Diego Perini (The above polyfill is better and CSSOM compliant, so you should probably use that.):

```
/*
 * How to detect which element is the scrolling element in charge of scrolling the viewport:
 *
 * - in Quirks mode the scrolling element is the "body"
 * - in Standard mode the scrolling element is the "documentElement"
 *
 * webkit based browsers always use the "body" element, disrespectful of the specifications:
 *
 *  http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrolltop
 *
 * This feature detection helper allow cross-browser scroll operations on the viewport,
 * it will guess which element to use in each browser both in Quirk and Standard modes.
 * See how this can be used in a "smooth scroll to anchors references" example here:
 *
 *  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/598365/scrollTo/scrollTo.html
 *
 * It is just a fix for possible differences between browsers versions (currently any Webkit).
 * In case the Webkit bug get fixed someday, it will just work if they follow the specs. Win !
 *
 * Author: Diego Perini
 * Updated: 2014/09/18
 * License: MIT
 *
 */
function getScrollingElement() {
  var d = document;
  return  d.documentElement.scrollHeight > d.body.scrollHeight &&
          d.compatMode.indexOf('CSS1') == 0 ?
          d.documentElement :
          d.body;
}
```

— [getScrollingElement.js](https://gist.github.com/dperini/ac3d921d6a08f10fd10e)