# HTML - Which element has the page's scrollbar: <BODY> or <HTML>?

Tags: html, scroll, standards

In a simple, compliant HTML document, where the content in the <BODY> element is of greater height than the browser's viewport, a vertical scrollbar will appear on the right (unless the scrollbar is disabled, of course).

When this happens, which element is the scrollbar attached to: <BODY> or <HTML>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, at least in Chrome, `<html>`. You can test this by scrolling down on this page and comparing `document.body.scrollTop` to `document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0).scrollTop`.

There is nothing requiring that you maintain this choice, and you are able to override this default behavior using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking to know how element attach the CSS property `overflow`, this doesn't matter. You can attach it to `<html>` or to `<body>`, as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

as **David Murdoch** described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837178/how-to-determine-if-html-or-body-scrolls-the-window) this is the best way to know

```js
function getScrollingElement() {
  var d = document;
  return d.documentElement.scrollHeight > d.body.scrollHeight &&
    d.compatMode.indexOf('CSS1') == 0 ?
    d.documentElement :
    d.body;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try Adding:

```
   * {
outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

Then when you scroll down you can see tall box (big one) after you right click on it to inspect element Then you should see all the information you need.